# Using Python decorators to delete files after uploading

Tags: python, pandas, slack

Trying to wrap my head around decorators in Python

I am trying to write a class which contains 2 functions:

1. A function which takes a pandas DataFrame as an argument and writes it to a text file, using tabulate.

```
def text_file(filename, df):
    table = tabulate(filename, tablefmt="grid", headers=df.columns)
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(table)
```

2. A function to upload files to Slack and delete it after 5 seconds

```
slack = Slacker(api_token)

def upload(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def upload_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        slack.files.upload(file,
                          channels=channel, 
                          title=head,
                          initial_comment=comment)

        time.sleep(5)
        os.remove(file)
    return upload_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am getting tripped up on understanding how to use decorators and how to use args and kwargs.

The end result of my structure would be something like:

```
from slacker import Slacker
from tabulate import tabulate
import functools
import time, os

class Slack:
    def __init__(self, api_token, channel):
        self.Slacker = Slacker(api_token)
        self.channel = channel

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def upload(func):
        def upload_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.slack.files.upload(file, 
                                    channels=self.channel,
                                    title=head,
                                    initial_comment=comment)
            time.sleep(5)
            os.remove(file)
        return upload_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def generate_text_file(self, filename, df):
        table = tabulate(filename, tablefmt="grid", headers=df.columns)
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(table)
```

And my desired result would be to call a function which prepares a file for me, then uploads it to Slack and deletes it so no files are kept on the system (I would have this running via a cronjob).

```
workspace_name = Slack(api_token, channel=channel_name)

df = some_pandas_function()

@upload
workspace_name.generate_text_file("filename.txt", df)
```

Any help would be much appreciated ...

Comment: I've never seen a decorator being applied to an expression in python. Are you sure that's legal to begin with? It looks like you should instead call the function with the expression as an argument

Comment: why wouldn't be legal??